# How can I compare just the file contents of two zip files

Tags: linux, zip, comparison

I created these two zip files about 24 hours apart.

```
$ ls -l /tmp/*.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 scott scott 1401289 Mar 21 20:11 /tmp/inc1.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 scott scott 1401289 Mar 22 19:29 /tmp/inc2.zip
```

You can see they're the same size, because the directory being zipped hasn't changed.

However, these files have been viewed in the last 24 hours, so their access times have changed.  For this reason, I can't compare the zips using diff or cmp.

What would a way to reliably compare their contents be?  For example, I am considering comparing the output of

```
ls -l <file> | awk '{print $5}'
```

on the two files.   Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[zipcmp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zipcmp)

> zipcmp compares the zip archives zip1 and zip2 and checks if they
>   contain the same files, comparing their names, uncompressed sizes, and
>   CRCs. File order and compressed size differences are ignored.